# Delete Columns of a Worksheet upto a variable range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet which the columns after C are all relevant to specific weeks e.g. Week 1, Week 2. I need to keep columns A-C but then i need to delete all columns other than the CURRENT week number and the two columns to the right of it.

This is a rather large spreadsheet and the current week number is now upto Collumn CK, but this will have to self update every week.

The Week no. are displayed on the second Row.

Also I need to copy the cells from the current week and the two columns adjacent to it.

Please help me i have searched every where for a solution and tried everything.

I can get the current week number using

```
iNumberOfTheWeek = DatePart("ww", Now()) 
'// current number of of the week in the year
```

But don't know how to utilize this

Answer (score 0):

I think SO recommends more effort shown in the question, but here's a lot for you anyway:

```
Sub Sub1()
  Dim iNumberOfTheWeek&, FindCol&
  Dim FindRange As Range, delRange As Range, copyRange As Range
  iNumberOfTheWeek = DatePart("ww", Now())
  ' the range to search
  Set FindRange = Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(2, Columns.Count))
  Debug.Print FindRange.Address
  ' find the current week
  Set FindRange = FindRange.Find(iNumberOfTheWeek, LookIn:=xlValues)
  If FindRange Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Not found": End
  Debug.Print FindRange.Address
  FindCol = FindRange.Column
  ' the first (left) range to delete
  Set delRange = Range(Columns(4), Columns(FindCol - 1))
  Debug.Print delRange.Address
  delRange.Delete
  ' the second (right) range to delete
  Set delRange = Range(Columns(7), Columns(Columns.Count))
  Debug.Print delRange.Address
  delRange.Delete
  ' the range to copy
  Set copyRange = Columns(3).Resize(Rows.Count, 3) ' 3, 4, and 5
  Debug.Print copyRange.Address
  copyRange.Copy
  '?? do what
End Sub
```